# Unable to import module Diagnostics. No manifest was found

Tags: azure, azure-diagnostics

I am creating an Windows Azure Service and added a Worker Role. I am creating this in Visual Studio 2013 RC. When I open properties of my worker role the following error shows:

```
Unable to Import Module Diagnostics. No menifest was found
```

**ServiceDefinition.csdef**

```
       <Imports>
        <Import moduleName="Diagnostics" />
    </Imports>
    <Startup priority="-2">
        <Task commandLine="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching\ClientPerfCountersInstaller.exe install" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple" />
    </Startup>
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" />
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Caching.ClientDiagnosticLevel"/>
    </ConfigurationSettings>
</WorkerRole>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had it fixed by repairing installation of Windows Azure Tools for my VS version.