# Azure web role build error: "Unable to import module Diagnostics. No manifest was found"

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-cloud-services

We have a C# web application solution configured to run on Azure cloud services. It's an old solution and builds fine locally on other engineers' laptops (has done for years), and on my previous laptop. But I have a new laptop where I've set up my development environment but this particular solution does not build.

There are two related build errors:

- `Unable to import module Diagnostics.  No manifest was found.` in _ServiceDefinition.csdef _(part of the ccproj project)
- `CloudServices58 : Cannot load imported module named 'Diagnostics.'` at *C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\Windows Azure Tools\2.9\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets*

[image: VS error: "Unable to import module Diagnostics. No manifest was found]

The *ServiceDefinition.csdef* file includes this section:

```
<Imports>
    <Import moduleName="Diagnostics" />
    <Import moduleName="RemoteAccess" />
    <Import moduleName="RemoteForwarder" />
</Imports>
```

If I remove that first `Import` line then the build succeeds.

I've searched everywhere for a solution. There are a couple of similar questions here on SO but the answers usually come down to installation of Azure SDK, but I can confirm I have this installed at this location:

*C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure.NET SDK\v2.9*

I've run out of options. Can any of you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be that the Azure SDK 2.9 that gets installed by Visual Studio setup is missing the Diagnostics plugin. On a working (old) machine, go to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\ .NET SDK\v2.9\bin\plugins and copy the Diagnostics folder into the same location on the new computer.

Comment: Thank you. Finally a solution that works for me. My colleagues were getting really annoyed with me accidentally committing a commented out `<Import moduleName="Diagnostics" />` into PRs!!

Comment: By the way. Slight typo in your directory path. Correct location is _C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\.NET SDK\v2.9\bin\plugins\Diagnostics_

Answer (score 0):

Please check the steps if helps to work around:

- Check the `Import Module Diagnostics Code` is under the ***WebRole*** in `ServiceDefinition.csdef` file.
- Configure `Web.config` file to add ***Diagnostics Module*** for Listeners type like:

```
<system.diagnostics>
<trace>
<listeners>
<add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener,
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics,
Version=1.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
name="AzureDiagnostics">
<filter type=""/>
</add>
</listeners>
</trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

- Configuring the Azure Storage Account in the `ServiceConfiguration.cscfg`

```
<ConfigurationSettings>
<Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=[youracountnamehere];AccountKey=[youraccountkeyhere]/>
</ConfigurationSettings>
<Certificates>
</Certificates>
</Role>
</ServiceConfiguration>
```

- Similar kind of issue is resolved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19428249/unable-to-import-module-diagnostics-no-manifest-was-found) by re-installing the Windows Azure Tools of VS.
- This issue has been addressing since Azure SDK 2.4 even there is no code dependent but need those modules to collect the data for debugging purposes. Try to uninstall and install again, the Azure Development Tools and its included SDK Components in VS:
  Visual Studio > Tools > Get Tools & Features:

[image]

**References:**

- [Azure Diagnostics Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/hh411537(v=azure.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [VS Azure Tools and SDK 2.9 Installer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-visual-studio-azure-tools-and-sdk-2-9/)

Comment: Thank you but none of this works for me. The first three bullet points are already implemented (works on many other laptops in my team), and I've reinstalled the whole of Visual Studio (2022 Enterprise) as well as the individual Azure components. Your VS Azure Tools and SDK 2.9 Installer link takes me to a page listing a few versions. I chose the Visual Studio “15” Preview version but when executed the Web Platform Installer says it can't find the requested product ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with "Caching" import. This worked for me:

[Click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4N7uw.png)

The "Caching" folder was missing from the Plugins folder, so I copied it from a machine that was working. i.e. check for a missing "Diagnostics" folder.

Comment: This seems like a new problem posted as an answer. Yes, they are both related to a missing dependency, but they're very different types of dependencies. It may make more sense to post this as a new question which you then answer yourself.